# Unique Count (Print out 0) within Time Range

Tags: sql, count, sum

I have a table `TB` contains columns `Time, User_id, State` with data as below.

```
INSERT INTO TB
  (Time, User_id, State)
VALUES
  (1, 1, 'VA'),
  (1, 2, 'VA'),
  (1, 2, 'DC'),
  (2, 1, 'VA'),
  (2, 2, 'MD'),
  (3, 1, 'MD'),
  (3, 112, 'MD'),
  (3, 134, 'VA'),
  (3, 111, 'MD'),
  (4, 12, 'VA'),
  (4, 22, 'MD')
;
```

I would like a unique count of `User_id` given `State = 'DC'` every 2 seconds. The result should be looking like this:

```
NewTime | Count  
   1    |  1
   2    |  0
```

I got answer to print out 0 when the count is 0 using

```
SELECT  TIME,
        SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'DC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Count
FROM    TB
GROUP   BY Time
```

And get the unique count within a time range using

```
SELECT
    ((Time - 1) / 2) + 1 as NewTime,
    COUNT(DISTINCT User_id) as Count
FROM ... 
GROUP BY ((Time - 1) / 2) + 1
```

But I'm not sure how to combine these two to get the result I want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
SELECT
    ((Time - 1) / 2) + 1 as NewTime,
    COUNT(DISTINCT case when state = 'DC' then User_id end) as Count
FROM ... 
GROUP BY ((Time - 1) / 2) + 1
```

This assumes that you have some record (though not necessarily DC) every two seconds.